# SDL Web 8.5 <tcdl:Comment>s are printing on the jsp website as is

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, tcdl

We are upgrading from 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5. After the upgrade `<tcdl:comment>` is printing on the website. We have contacted SDL CS for the Hotfix that we need to apply after 8.5 upgrade that is related to `cd_tcdl_conf.xml`. This is a JSP website.

1. Does applying this Hotfix **CD_8.5.0.1876.zip**(mentioned here https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000006143) will also  resolve the `<tcdl:comment>`  issue as well?
2. Also Component Links are not resolving on the website. Internal links are broken.

Could you please help if you have any work around for this issue. PFA screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Answers can be helpful and are definitely appreciated, but do continue the discussion with Support and report back results here to help others that are upgrading.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the Hotfix", can you please **edit** your question and specify what hotfix you are exactly talking about, since they all have a unique number.

Comment: @Bart - Sorry this is the Hotfix I meant "CD_8.5.0.1876.zip" related to <tcdl> tags. Let me update my question with the Hotfix number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, Applying the Hotfix **"CD_8.5.0.1876"**, fixed our `<tcdl:comment>` tags related and component link resolving issues.

I hope this helps for those who are upgrading from 2013 SP1 to Web 8.5. We need to install the **CD_8.5.0.1876** Hotfix after the upgrade.